# First time group meets condition in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, partition-by

I have the following `pandas.DataFrame`:

|  | id | year | x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01001 | 2015 | 0 |
| 1 | 01001 | 2016 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 01001 | 2017 | 0 |
| 3 | 01001 | 2018 | 0 |
| 4 | 01002 | 2015 | 0 |
| 5 | 01002 | 2016 | 0 |
| 6 | 01002 | 2017 | 0.0667525 |
| 7 | 01002 | 2018 | 0.133505 |

My goal is to create a new column and fill each window with `1`'s one row after `x > 0` for the first time and fill all preceding rows with `0`. That is:

|  | id | year | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01001 | 2015 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 01001 | 2016 | 0.5 | 0 |
| 2 | 01001 | 2017 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 01001 | 2018 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 01002 | 2015 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 01002 | 2016 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 01002 | 2017 | 0.0667525 | 0 |
| 7 | 01002 | 2018 | 0.133505 | 1 |

How can this be done?

This is what I came up with: Get each group's index the first time `x > 0` and fill each window with `1` from that index until the end of the partition. Then, take these indices and replace their rows with `0`.

Here's a replicable example of my data:

```py
t = pd.DataFrame({'id':{0:'01001',1:'01001',2:'01001',3:'01001',4:'01002',5:'01002',6:'01002',7:'01002'},
                  'x':{0:0.0,1:0.5,2:0,3:0,4:0.0,
                        5:0.0,6:0.06675245612859726,7:0.13350491651818122},
                  'year':{0:2015,1:2016,2:2017,3:2018,4:2015,5:2016,6:2017,7:2018}})
t
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, have you tried  `df['y'] = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).apply(lambda p: (p['x'].shift().gt(0)).astype(int)).droplevel(0, axis=0)`?

Comment: Ah! So close! I hope this last edit showcases my problem better.

Comment: Yap, use cumsum, `df['y'] = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).apply(lambda p: (p['x'].shift().gt(0)).cumsum()).droplevel(0, axis=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about checking consecutive occurrence conditionally?

```
df['y'] = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).apply(lambda p: (p['x'].shift().gt(0)).cumsum()).droplevel(0, axis=0)



    id  year         x   y
0  1001  2015  0.000000  0
1  1001  2016  0.500000  0
2  1001  2017  0.000000  1
3  1001  2018  0.000000  1
4  1002  2015  0.000000  0
5  1002  2016  0.000000  0
6  1002  2017  0.066753  0
7  1002  2018  0.133505  1
```

Comment: This is actually really clever. Can you do the same grouping by `id`? In its current form, I don't think this would work whenever the first row of a group starts off being >0.

Comment: Do you mean, `df['y'] = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).apply(lambda p: (p['x'].gt(0)&p['x'].shift().gt(0)).astype(int)).droplevel(0, axis=0)`?

Comment: I'm trying to think if this would work if a group shows the following behavior: `0, .5, 0, 0`. That's the whole reason I was trying to fetch the first occurrence. Regardless, I think this solves most of my issues.

Comment: Modify your input, output for clarity. Hower looks to me like your intial question was answered :-)

Comment: What if we tried `df['y'] = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).apply(lambda p: (p['x'].shift().gt(0)).astype(int)).droplevel(0, axis=0)`?

Comment: Have you tried `df['y'] = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).apply(lambda p: (p['x'].shift().gt(0)).cumsum()).droplevel(0, axis=0)`

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `transform`:

```py
df['y'] = (df.index > (df['x']>0).groupby(df['id']).transform('idxmax')).astype(int)
df
      id  year         x  out
 0  1001  2015  0.000000    0
 1  1001  2016  0.500000    0
 2  1001  2017  0.000000    1
 3  1001  2018  0.000000    1
 4  1002  2015  0.000000    0
 5  1002  2016  0.000000    0
 6  1002  2017  0.066753    0
 7  1002  2018  0.133505    1
```

Comment: Hi Beny. Could you explain how `transform('idxmax')` works?

Comment: @ArturoSbr get the first position of value who more than 0 for all groupby each item , then you can compare their index ~

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `cumprod`

```
df.groupby('id')['x'].transform(lambda x: (~x.eq(0).shift().cumprod().astype(bool)).astype(int))
```